# What is the meaning of the LOG in the Android?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I get this loges in the android studio .
I want to understand the meaning of the errors.

[image]

Comment: It means file you are trying to access doesn't exist.

Comment: This log output is not from your app and you can probably just ignore it. There's a lot of background radiation in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `IllegalStateException`
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Your second `FileNotFoundException`
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

for your problem please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Usually, logs are pretty damn descriptive; oftentimes you can deduce what the problem is solely by looking at the Exception name and a bit of **stacktrace**. If you're unable to find the error, you can google your Exception.

Also, you can easily track the place where the Exception was thrown by clicking the **bolded** text, in your example:

> at java.io.FileInputStream.(**FileInputStream.java:78**)